# StackOverFlowError ao tentar chamar método recursivo

Tags: java, recursão

Estou desenvolvendo um editor de imagens tipo o `Paint`, e não consigo fazer o método  do balde de tinta, a ideia é assim: (exemplo)

Tenho uma matriz 8x8 e os possíveis valores neste exemplo são "-", "X" ou "O"

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
0 [-][-][-][-][-][-][-][x]
1 [-][-][-][-][-][-][x][-]
2 [-][-][-][-][-][x][-][-]
3 [-][-][-][-][x][-][-][-]
4 [-][-][-][-][x][-][-][-]
5 [-][-][x][x][-][-][-][-]
6 [-][x][-][-][-][-][-][-]
7 [x][-][-][-][-][-][-][-]
```

no meu método eu escolho um campo que tem um "-", então ele e todos os pampos dos lados ou em cima ou em baixo que são "-", se tornam "O" e este é um método recursivo, exemplo: pinta(5,6);

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
0 [-][-][-][-][-][-][-][x]
1 [-][-][-][-][-][-][x][o]
2 [-][-][-][-][-][x][o][o]
3 [-][-][-][-][x][o][o][o]
4 [-][-][-][-][x][o][o][o]
5 [-][-][x][x][o][o][o][o]
6 [-][x][o][o][o][o][o][o]
7 [x][o][o][o][o][o][o][o]
```

meu código implementando em um `bufferedImage` ao invés de uma matriz:

```
public static void pinta(BufferedImage buff,int x,int y,int color)
{
        int filtro=buff.getRGB(x,y);
        buff.setRGB(x,y,color);
        if(filtro!=color){
            if(buff.getRGB(x+1, y)==filtro){
                pinta(buff,x+1,y,color);
            }
            if(buff.getRGB(x-1, y)==filtro){
                pinta(buff,x-1,y,color);
            }
            if(buff.getRGB(x, y+1)==filtro){
                pinta(buff,x,y+1,color);
            }
            if(buff.getRGB(x, y-1)==filtro){
                pinta(buff,x,y-1,color);
            }
        }
    }
```

esse código funciona para o exemplo da matriz porque é muito pequeno, mas quando eu tento em uma imagem grande, maior que `200px` por `200px` mais ou menos, ele da `StackOverflowError`, não tem haver com o fato de eu não ter colocado uma condição para evitar o `CordenatesOffBoundException`, considerando que isso não vai acontecer no meu exemplo para facilitar.
Então como eu faço esse método sem utilizar recurção? alguém pode me dar um exemplo de código?

Comment: Em geral, stack overflow é causado quando a memória dedicada ao programa fica cheia com chamadas de função. Uma saída é vc tratar os dados em batches - em partes.

Comment: Então não use recursão.

Comment: Poderia disponibilizar o log do erro?